# Sending data from notification click to child activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have two activities, one called SplashActivity which is the Launcher and the main activity of the app and the second called MainActivity which is the child activity of SplashActivity, based on some event i have a notification created and when notification click i want the MainActivity to open and send data in extra.
My problem is i have tried every solution pops in front of me nothing worked.

this is my current code:

```
NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(String.valueOf(12), name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    channel.setDescription(description);
    // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
    // or other notification behaviors after this
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());
    notificationManagerCompat.createNotificationChannel(channel);

    // Create an Intent for the activity you want to start
    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashActivity.class);
    notifyIntent.putExtra("notify", "notify");
    notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        // Create the PendingIntent
       PendingIntent notifyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this, 0, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                    | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, String.valueOf(12))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{0, 100, 1000, 300})
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(notifyPendingIntent)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
    notificationManagerCompat.notify(12, notification);
```

two activities declaration in manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".home.activities.MainActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity" />

    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**any one what is the solution? and why my current code is not working?**

please help me i been working two days for this to work.

Comment: Could you add your code when you open MainActivity from SplashActivity?

Comment: @CôngHải I just did.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot putExtra to intent when start MainActivity, you only show log. Try this

```
        Intent i = new Intent(this, destinationActivity);
        i.putExtras(getIntent());
        Log.e(TAG, "navigateTo: " + getIntent().getStringExtra("notify"));
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
```

Comment: the log statement printing null in the log file, why would i send null value to MainActivity!!

Comment: In case from notification you should pass it to MainActivity. because intent start SplashActivity has data

Comment: there are no data coming from intent.

Comment: What launch mode you set for SplashActivity?, I means inside AndroidManifest

Comment: it don't have a launch mode.

Answer (score 0):

after a while trying different solutions i didn't know what the problem is.

but what i did is i used this code:

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null)
        getIntent().getExtras().keySet().iterator().forEachRemaining(new Consumer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(String s) {
                Log.e(TAG, "accept: " + s);
            }
        });
```

to print out the extras keys i have when the activity opens from notification i saw a unique set of keys and i used one of them as trigger for specific action when it opens from notification.